# How to bind a Kendo DropDownList to an Observable class?

Tags: jquery, json, data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm having problems in making a DropDownList work with an Observable class.

Here's the code for the observable class:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            dsMember: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 6,
                error: function (e) {
                    top.CustomError(e);
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "GET",
                        url: function () {
                            return "../api/Member/" + viewModel.MemberParam;
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function (e) {
                            viewModel.set("SelectedMember", viewModel.dsMember.view()[0]);
                        }
                    },
                    update: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../api/Member",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function (e, textStatus) { top.CustomSuccess(e, textStatus); }
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../api/Member",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function (e) {
                            viewModel.NewRecord();
                        }
                    },
                    create: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "PUT",
                        url: "../api/Member",
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function (e, textStatus) {
                            if (typeof (e.responseText) != "undefined") {
                                var response = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);
                                var obj = viewModel.dsMember.view()[viewModel.dsMember.view().length - 1];
                                obj.MemberId = response.MemberId;
                                viewModel.set("SelectedMember", obj);
                                document.getElementById("tbMemberId").value = obj.MemberId;

                                top.CustomSuccess(e, textStatus);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "MemberId",
                        fields: {
                            MemberId: {
                                type: "number",
                                editable: false // this field is not editable
                            },
                            MemberName: {
                                type: "text",
                                validation: { // validation rules
                                    required: true // the field is required
                                }
                            },
                            id_function_club: {
                                type:"number"
                            },
                            name_function_club: {
                                type: "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            MemberParam: 0,
            SelectedMember: null,
            save: function () {
                this.dsMember.sync();
            },

            remove: function () {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
                    this.dsMember.remove(this.SelectedMember);
                    this.set("SelectedMember", this.dsMember.view()[0]);
                    this.save();
                }
            },
            NewRecord: function () {
                var newRecord = new viewModel.dsMember.reader.model();
                newRecord.MemberId = null;
                viewModel.dsMember.add(newRecord);
                viewModel.set("SelectedMember", viewModel.dsMember.view()[viewModel.dsMember.view().length - 1]);
            }
        });
```

---

And here is my working DropDownList:

```
$("#ddFunctionClub").kendoDropDownList({
            height: 150,
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataValueField: "id_function_club",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "GET",
                        url: function () {
                            return "../api/Function_Club";
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

---

Here's my html for the DropDownList:

```
<input id="ddFunctionClub" style="width: 100%;" />
```

---

And finally, this is what I'm getting back from the observable datasource request:

```
{"MemberId":123,"MemberName":"Person","BirthDate":"10/01/1980","id_function_club":2,"name_function_club":"My Function","NameUnit":"My Unit"}
```

---

I did some research, but couldn't find any suitable example.

I looked at:
[MVVM Widget Binding](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/widgets.html) and played around with data-bind, data-value-field, data-text-field but couldn't get the results I wanted.

Therefore, **what I'm looking for is**, a way of binding a regular DropDownList (one that is tied to a datasource) to an Observable class. For example, the text would be bound to SelectedMember.name_function_club and the value to SelectedMember.id_function_club.

Can you help?

If something is not quite clear, please leave a comment asking for more info.

THANKS!

Comment: I don't know what are you trying but looks a pretty complex to me. kendoDrowDownList already accept a DataSource that are Observable. Why you do not use it as it is? Did you check http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/remotedatasource.html?

Comment: Hey #OnaBai, thanks for your response. I did look at that, actually, that's what my dropdownlist is currently doing. What I want is to have the id_function and name_function values of the ViewModel bound to the id_function and name_function values of the DropDown. So that when I load the viewmodel the dropdown automatically changes values, and also when I change the dropdown values the viewmodel automatically knows that something has changed.

Comment: Without your viewmodel you can load it using dropdownlist.dataSource.read() for loading it and the dropdownlist should get automatically updated. Still can't get why you need two datasources.

Comment: Maybe I don't need two datasources. If that's the case, can you be more specific on how to do it?

Comment: I'm still not following I guess... (sorry about that)... look at the json response from the viewmodel request. See that there is a id_function_club and name_function_club. How can I have the dropdownlist set with those values (through the viewmodel)?

Comment: Let me prepare some example code for you. I let you know asap

Comment: That will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please, see my answer. I hope it is close enough to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your case, you don't actually need two `DataSources`. One is enough since they are actually `Observable` and any update on it will be propagated to the `DropDownList`.

Lets define the `kendoDropDownList` as follow:

```
$("#ddFunctionClub").kendoDropDownList({
    height        : 150,
    dataTextField : "name_function_club",
    dataValueField: "id_function_club",
    dataSource    : dataSource
});
```

And the minimum `DataSource` would be:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type     : "json",
    transport: {
        read: "xyz"
    }
});
```

*NOTE:* I say *minimum* `transport` since it can be as complex as you need (like the original one that include many operations.

The data received from the server (as far as I understand from the OP) would be an array of objects as the one that you included.

```
var data = [
    {"MemberId": 123, "MemberName": "Person", "BirthDate": "10/01/1980", "id_function_club": 1, "name_function_club": "My Function 1", "NameUnit": "My Unit"},
    {"MemberId": 123, "MemberName": "Person", "BirthDate": "10/01/1980", "id_function_club": 2, "name_function_club": "My Function 2", "NameUnit": "My Unit"},
    {"MemberId": 123, "MemberName": "Person", "BirthDate": "10/01/1980", "id_function_club": 3, "name_function_club": "My Function 3", "NameUnit": "My Unit"},
    {"MemberId": 123, "MemberName": "Person", "BirthDate": "10/01/1980", "id_function_club": 4, "name_function_club": "My Function 4", "NameUnit": "My Unit"}
];
```

As soon as you change the DataSource, the `DropDownList` is changed (for example, add or remove elements or change their content).

See an example in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/DtbQY/#base.
If you press the button `Change DataSource` the list is automatically updated (insert two elements and update the second one).

Comment: OnaBai! Thank you for your answer. I think we have different perspectives of what I'm wanting to accomplish, so I can't say this was the exact answer for my problem, but certainly led me to the right path. Thanks